# Hyperlink to EXE file

Tags: asp.net, html, iis-7

I have created a simple windows .EXE that copies files from one location to another on a target computer.

However, on the website that I'm testing this on, I created a hyperlink:

```
<a href="CustomApp.exe">Here</a> is the download.
```

However, when I click on the link, it attempts to start CustomApp.exe which is not what I want to happen.  I want to prompted to accept the user file, *then* run it.

Is this something I need to configure on an IIS 7 machine, or in my ASP.NET page?

Comment: What type of browser are you using? Are you running the website on your computer accessing it locally? If the website if on a remote site your browser should warn you. If not then may be you changed your browser's default security level.

Comment: @bdhac - I'm using both IE 8 and IE 9.  I'm running the website within the company's network.  The interesting thing is that I have another link below it that points to a different .EXE via a hyperlink that does behave the way that I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

It's the way your server serves that mime-type. Might have to configure it differently or serve the download using a php/asp.net page and edit the headers.

Some more explanation on how to do this in asp.net from asawyer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhy78ycf(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You can change the headers in asp.net through the Response object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhy78ycf(v=vs.71).aspx